# Display list of all registered beacons

Tags: python, flask, google-beacon-platform

I am working with beacons and want to display all the registered beacons on a same web page by making the `request` in python.

I am confused, After setting up the scope of OAuth2, how to send the `request` or `discovery.build()` to get list of all the requests.

I am setting up the scope by this:

```
@portal.route('/oauth2callback')
def oauth2callback():
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(
        'client_secrets.json',
        scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userlocation.beacon.registry',
        redirect_uri=flask.url_for('portal.oauth2callback', _external=True),
    )
    if 'code' not in flask.request.args:
        auth_uri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
        return flask.redirect(auth_uri)
    else:
        auth_code = flask.request.args.get('code')
        credentials = flow.step2_exchange(auth_code)
        flask.session['credentials'] = credentials.to_json()
        return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('portal.index'))



@portal.route('/')
def index():
    if 'credentials' not in flask.session:
        return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('portal.oauth2callback'))
    credentials = client.OAuth2Credentials.from_json(
        flask.session['credentials']
    )
    if credentials.access_token_expired:
        return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('portal.oauth2callback'))
    else:
        http_auth = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
        drive_service = discovery.build('# What should I write')
        # Or, requests.get(What should I write)
```

Can some one help me how to get list of all registered beacons by making the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It get done by sending request like:

```
sess = requests.Session()
req = sess.get('https://proximitybeacon.googleapis.com/v1beta1/beacons', headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer '+credentials.access_token})
```

Answer (score 0):

Hrm. I don't have much experience with Python, but I'm pretty sure there are Google Sign-In clients for python such as here on [GitHub](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client).

With this you can integrate a login flow to your app.

Then, when you make calls to the Proximity Beacon Admin API, to auth you just have to set the HTTP header:

```
Authorization: Bearer <<OAUTH_BEARER_TOKEN_HERE>>
```

and your call should be authenticated properly. Then you can do the python equivalent of like http.get() or http.post(), add that HTTP header, and you should be able to see responses.

Comment: Here Authorisation is not a problem, problem is how will you use Proximity API to render the list of all registered beacons.

Comment: You use the [beacons.list method](https://proximitybeacon.googleapis.com/v1beta1/beacons). If you don't specify a `q` query parameter, then you will get ALL the beacons. You can use the `pageSize` and the `pageToken` query parameters to iterate over the complete list of your beacons.